# Physicality of post-measurement description of a state based on information of measurement outcomes

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-states, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-measurements

Say, we find two exact systems in a pure state. When Alice does von Neumann measurement on it, the state collapse to a **pure state** because Alice knows the measurement outcomes. In this case, we have $\rho \rightarrow \frac{P\rho P}{Tr(P\rho P)}$ where $P$ is just a projection. Meanwhile, Bob does the same von Neumann measurement on another same system, but it turns out, due to several reasons, he doesn't have the measurement outcomes, but the measurement has been done. In this case, the post-measurement state, according to Bob, is a **mixed state**, and we have $\rho \rightarrow \sum {P\rho P}$.

Similarly, say Alice and Bob work on the same system and do a measurement. Alice happens to know the measurement outcomes, but Bob doesn't. Based on similar arguments above, this means that Alice and Bob have different post-measurement states, in the sense that one has a pure state description and another has a mixed state description (for the same system!).

How can a state be mixed (and therefore be a statistical ensemble) to Bob while the same state is pure to Alice? How do we interpret post-measurement states on the basis of how much information one obtains from a measurement? What does it mean for Bob to do a measurement but not know the measurement outcomes? Does it mean that he somehow forgot it? Does the state go back from being a mixed state to a pure state if, somehow, someone tells Bob the measurement outcomes?

Comment: Note: Your *"(for the same state!)"* should really read *"(for the same system)"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that QM's predictions only concern ensembles of identical systems, the post measurement state on a given ensamble is always pictured as $\rho \to \sum_k P_k\rho P_k$.

In this case the initial ensemble has state $\rho$ and the same ensemble, after the measurement process,  has state $\sum_k P_k\rho P_k$.

However, we can focus attention on the sub-ensemble that produced a specific outcome, say,  $k_0$. That is possible  *if we are able to separate these systems from the rest of the ensemble*. This sub-ensemble is described by  $P_{k_0}\rho P_{k_0}$, and it  must be normalized to $\frac{P_{k_0}\rho P_{k_0}}{tr(P_{k_0}\rho)}$.

From this perspective, there is no collapse and every process is linear: the apparent collapse happens when you focus attention on a sub-ensemble and you decide that, from then on, the ensemble is  that sub-ensemble.
I stress that an objective physical change however *takes place* when the systems interact with the measurement apparatus. This process can be described in terms of the theory of quantum measurement (maybe eventually invoking some de-coherence process).

In summary:

Having only a single system of the ensemble at our disposal it is impossible to predict the outcome among the elements of the set $\{k\}$, since we are supposing that QM only describe ensembles.

However, if you know(*) that the measurement produced  $k_0$, you can attribute the state $\frac{P_{k_0}\rho P_{k_0}}{tr(P_{k_0}\rho)}$ to the ensemble of  that single system.

If you do not know the specific  outcome of a given system, the state is $\sum_k P_k\rho P_k$, simply because the only possible ensemble containing your system is the initial one.

There is no contradiction as the predictions regard probabilities and you can update the state on account of your knowledge. Different distributions of probabilities refer to different ensambles. If you know the value $k_0$, the reference ensamble is made of systems which received that outcome on measurement. In that situation, to test the predictions of QM, you should refer to such ensemble. Conversely,  if you do not know the outcome $k_0$, the reference ensamble includes all possibilities (according to $\sum P\rho P$) and, again, to test the (now different) predictions of QM, you should refer to that different ensamble.

All that happens also at classical level when you deal with systems described in terms of (conditional) probability.

If we instead  assume that the state is a property of a single system, then a list of problems pops out (I am not arguing  that the statistical interpretation is not affected by difficult issues!). In particular, it seems that the collapse should be an objective (physical) process. It is difficult to describe it in physical terms  (also in agreement with basic assumptions on local causality in particular).  Nevertheless noticeable attempts exist like the GRW spontaneous collapse...

The perspective that assumes that part of the quantum state is subjective (it reflects part of our information) may lead to the idea that all quantum indererminateness is of subjective nature and there is a true objective ("realistic") state hidden in the single system. This is the starting point of all hidden variable theories. As far as we know, this perspective is untenable unless dropping some fundamental requirement as locality or non-contextuality.

---

(*) The outcome of a measurement is an objective macroscopic information. It exists even if you do not know it for some practical reason.

Answer (score 2):

The state you assign to a quantum system depends on your knowledge, as it allows you predict outcomes of experiments performed on the state. The more information you have, the better predictions you can make. The amount of information you have thus does indeed change the state description you assign to a quantum system. It is completely fine that Alice and Bob assign different states to the same quantum system if they have different knowledge, and it is also fine that Bob will update his description once he learns additional information about the system, be it from measurement results he is told, or from further details about the state preparation, or from measurement outcomes performed on a another system entangled with the system under consideration.

Note that this is not at all quantum mechanical: The same is true if you throw a dice, and Alice looks at the dice, while Bob doesn't: They will assign a different probability distribution of outcomes to this dice.

Comment: While I do understand that, for the same system, it is okay to have different state descriptions for the same system, the question I had in my mind was that what Bob views as a statistical mixture of pure states is just a single pure state to Alice. Isn't that contradictory? How can a statistical mixture of states be a pure state to someone else?

Comment: If you adopt the point of view that a state description one assigns to a system is dependent on one's knowledge, this is not contradictory. To iterate, the same is true for a dice. The difference is that you can reason that the dice has a "real" value, even if Bob does not know it, while this is not the case in a quantum mechanical setting. But the very basic fact that A and B assign different descriptions to the same system, depending on their knowledge, is the same.